# Как выровнять input

Tags: html, css

мой input с классом but_get съезжает вверх а должен быть inline как это сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот мой html

```
<div id="button_get">
        <input id="but_get_1" type="text" class="but_get"/>
        <div><select id = "color_1" class="color" onchange = "color(this.id, this.value)">
            <option value="gr">Цвет</option>
            <option value="g">Зеленая</option>
            <option value="r">Красная</option>
            <option value="b">Синяя</option>
            <option value="w">Белая</option>
        </select></div>
        <div><label for="url_chek" id="url_chek_l">URL-кнопка</label>
        <input type="checkbox" value = "1" id="url_chek"/></div>
    </div>
```

Вот мой css:

```
#button_get div{
    display: inline;
}

.but_get{
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 31px;
}

#url_chek{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#url_chek_l{
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#button_get{
    margin-top: 25px;
    height: 50px;
}

.color{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 31px;
    width: 90px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Что означает съезжает вверх? В вашем коде все элементы стоят в ряд

Comment: добавил картинку

Comment: Создайте сниппет а не части кода, ваш пример строит все в ряд. На скрине это мобильная версия? Как они должны встать в ряд если по ширине не помещаются, какое поведение вы ожидаете? Я копирую Ваш код в сниппет и запускаю - все элементы стоят в ряд.

Comment: Если ваш код, который вы разместили на stackoverflow, стоит у вас не в ряд - уточните: браузер; ОС; ширину экрана;

Answer (score 0):

Если можно использовать флексы, то все просто. Родительскому блоку указываете display: flex;, затем выравниваете по центру их по центру align-items: center;. Проверил на jsfiddle, с использованием флексов все ровно.

```
#button_get{
   margin-top: 25px;
   height: 50px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin так, а что тут дополнять? Человек пишет, что у него input лезет вверх, я запустил на jsfiddle, да действительно, криво элементы расположены. Добавляешь display flex для родительского блока и ровняешь по центру через align-items: center; , элементарно. Ну, правда, если автор вопроса не признает флексы, то тогда ответ не правильный))

Comment: вот то, что вы в комментарии написали, почти в таком же виде можно было бы добавить в текст ответа. // думаю, стоит ориентироваться на [хорошее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ок, понял, думал, когда такие простые вещи достаточно кода) редко сижу здесь просто)

Answer (score 0):

Инлайновые элементы переносятся:

`#button_get {white-space: nowrap;}`